# Creating a Android Project throws Error "The tools must be updated via SDK manager"

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

When I'm creating an android project in eclipse juno version, It throws error like this `The tools need to be updated via the SDK Manager`. Please Help me

[image: Bug Image]

Comment: My android sdk is installed completely, Actually It is Update to Date

Comment: Did you check Prefernces->Android->SDK localtion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably haven't pointed Eclipse to your android-sdk folder yet.

In Eclipse, go to Preferences -> Android -> then in the SDK location text box, browse through your android-sdk folder.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your platform/sdk tools are incompatible with the version of ADT eclipse plugin you have installed. Most likely, the plugin is updated, and the tools are not.

This is why you need to update the tools using the SDK manager.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Robert, I updated both the SDK and ADT plugin, your solution helps me out

Answer (score 1):

None of the above worked for me. I had to "delete" SDK Build tools packages and then re-install the packages. After doing that, I could now create a new android project.